# How to navigate to Angular routes from ASP.NET backend

Tags: asp.net, angular

My back-end is in ASP.Net(.Net 4.6.2) and front-end in Angular 6. When I navigate to an angular route from the localhost, and refresh, all works fine:

```
http://localhost:4200/search
```

However, once I deploy it to a different host (IIS) the refresh of an Angular path will throw a 404 page:

```
http://otherhost/search
```

What is the best way to tell IIS to actually trigger the Angular route instead of controller one (which obviously does not exist)?

Comment: This may be of some help: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Check this, https://medium.com/@h.alhaj/angular-route-with-iis-shared-host-d8dfc80877c4

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts:

Import LocationStrategy and HashLocationStrategy from angular/common and use them in your module's provider section. For example:

```
import {} from '@angular/common';
...
providers: [
{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
}
...
]
```

Comment: His problem is with the server, when you request apphost/angularRoute angularRoute does not exist on the server an a 404 is encountered. The config needs to be done in IIS to serve the index.html instead and has nothing to to with Angular, this same issue occurs with any SPA that uses client side routing.

Hash routing is terrible advise.